# Search for singleton tags on questions

Tags: feature-request, tags, search

Is there any way to search for questions that have a specific tag and only that lonely tag?

In other words, I'd like to be able to do something like the following to find questions that have a single tag and no other:

```
[mytag] tagcount:1
```

This would be very useful for tag cleanup situations to be able to do house-cleaning before nuking a tag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I took the query in [this other answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148978/152859) and cleaned it up a bit, making it more generic:

```sql
Select Top 5000 Id As [Post Link], CreationDate
From Posts
Where Tags = Lower('<##Tag##>')
Order By CreationDate Desc
```

[SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/674540/find-questions-with-a-single-tag-now-case-insensitive).

Comment: `where title is not null`? I hope you meant `where posttypeid = 1`

Comment: @rene lol, as I said I just took existing query which worked, and just cleaned it up a bit. I'm pretty sure that if doing it from scratch, would have used the elegant way of checking the post type value. :)

Answer (score 5):

This query might help...

https://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/81422

It is specifically for Programmers but you can use it to search for questions with only a specific tag.

Comment: That's awesome, but the data explorer doesn't include beta sites!

Comment: @Caleb Yeah and the information is generally not updated frequently, as this is not production data.  It is really only useful if you were curious for analytical reasons.

Comment: I'm trying to do tag cleanup, so it would be nice it was actually live data so I could see progress as I re-tag things. +1 for a tangentially helpful bit though.

Comment: Also, welcome to Meta.SO! I feel honored to catch your first post ;)

Comment: @Caleb Thanks for the welcome!  Been lurking for a while, don't feel compelled to discuss things often.

Comment: @Caleb it include beta sites now. Enjoy!

Answer (score 3):

Using the API, you can find all questions that have a certain tag, then filter out the ones that have more than one tag. [Here is a demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/Ta28n/) that searches for questions tagged solely with [puncture](/questions/tagged/puncture) on [Bicycles](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com):

```
var tag = "puncture";
var site = "bicycles";

var url = 'http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/questions?sort=activity&callback=?';

var h3 = $('h3 span');

// Retrieve data
(function gather(cp, object) {
    if (typeof object === "undefined" || object.has_more) {
        $.getJSON(url, {
            site: site,
            tagged: tag,
            page: ++cp,
            key: "awn3X8U)9erzSfhBhqSF4A((",
            filter: "!BGS1(RNaQD-DYnwoUQeh2eZDaLm__P"
        }, function (data) {
            h3.html("(" + cp + " pages)")
            if (object) {
                data.items = data.items.concat(object.items);
            }
            gather(cp, data);
        });
    } else {
        display(object);
    }
})(0)

// Display data
function display(data) {
    var data = data.items;
    data = data.filter(function (v, i, A) {
        return v.tags.length == 1;
    });
    $.each(data, function (i, v) {
        var li = $('<li/>');
        var a = $('<a/>').attr('href', this.link).text(this.title);
        $('#results').append(li.append(a));
    });
    var heading = $('<h3/>').html('Total: ' + data.length);
    $('#results').prev().replaceWith(heading);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Fwiw, if you want to find *any* question with just one tag, regardless of the tag, you can use [a query like this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/674538?NumberOfTags=1):

```sql
SELECT TOP 50
  Id [Post Link], Tags, *
FROM
  Posts
WHERE
  LEN(Tags) - LEN(REPLACE(Tags, '<', '')) = 1 -- # of <'s = # of tags
ORDER BY
  CreationDate DESC
```

An alternate trick in the case of just one tag is `Tags NOT LIKE '%><%'`.