# Bookmarking search query using javascript

Tags: bug, search, javascript, firefox, bookmarks

Please provide me search queries for the below criteria,So that I can bookmark these links in my browser or use it in search box of Stackoverflow.

1. Search all **questions** tagged **ONLY java** and asked **today**. Below query results into some other questions with other tags along with java:

   "**[java]** is:question created:2013-11-28" Note that I can't use today in search query

   Instead of entering today's date daily on my machine. I want a dynamic query/**bookmarklet** in my browser(firefox), so that when I click on this bookmark I will get questions created on that particular day automatically
2. I am not able to copy paste the below query in search text box

   **[java]** is:question created:2011-01-05 or **[eclipse]** is:question created:2011-01-05 or **[swt]** is:question created:2011-01-05 or **[jface]** is:question created:2011-01-05 **[eclipse-plugin]** is:question created:2011-01-05 **[e4]** is:question created:2011-01-05 **[eclipse-rcp]** is:question created:2011-01-05 or **[egit]** is:question created:2011-01-05
3. When tried below query, I am getting questions tagged android, jar etc also

   [java] is: question created:2013-11-28 or [eclipse] is:question created:2013-11-28

Comment: Remember that 'Today' is potentially different for many users. Why not just search for `[java]` and then sort results by date? - like this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java?sort=newest&pageSize=50

Comment: OK. But how to exclude other tags and include only java tag in search results

Comment: @ChandrayyaGK - I don't know why do you want to search questions **only** tagged with Java. How will it help anyone to exclude Java tag when multiple tags is used?

Comment: So you want to show **only** `[Java]` questions and not, for example, questions tagged `[Java]` and `[string]`? Why?

Comment: Yes.Because I am not interested in questions tagged [java] and [android]

Comment: @ChandrayyaGK not possible, see linked dupe for workaround using Data Explorer.

Comment: @ChandrayyaGK Yes, but almost every question has more than one tag. You want to exclude questions with more than one tag? You'll get almost no questions

Comment: @ChandrayyaGK - Then you can exclude specific tag like this: [`[java] -[android]`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+-android)

Comment: @RichardTringle In that case I use query like this: [java] or [eclipse]. But this also results in some unwanted questions(See point 3 in my question)i.e I will get question tagged android along with java or eclipse tags.

Comment: Yes, just put -[android] in

Answer (score 3):

### Excluding specific tags

You can exclude specific tags using the `-` notation. For example the following searches for questions tagged java but not tagged [html] or [android].

```
[java] -[html] -[android]
```

If you would like you can add a `created:2013-11-28` but to make it reusuable it is probably easier to just sort by creation date

You can then just copy the URL at the top of your browser to bookmark these pages

### Excluding all other tags

I don't think you actually want this, because most questions (and almost all properly tagged questions) are tagged with at least one other tag. For example [string] or [arraylist]. If you really must have **just** [java] then there is no standard way to do this within the site but [there is a data explorer query that may help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148978/220332)

Answer (score 2):

1. Searching questions only tagged with java is not possible. Because almost all questions are tagged with more than one tag. If you want to ignore any tag in your search result you can exclude that tag with minus(`-`) keyword like this: [`[java] -[android]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+-android)
2. The maximum length of a query is [240](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209144/highly-upvoted-and-accepted-link-only-answer/209145?noredirect=1#comment669158_209145). Also your query is wrong. You don't need to show `is:q created:2013-11-28` every time. Instead try the query given in the 3rd point below.
3. Use the below query to search questions tagged with either [java](/questions/tagged/java) or [eclipse](/questions/tagged/eclipse) created on `2013-11-28`:

   [`[java] or [eclipse] is:question created:2013-11-28`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D%20or%20%5Beclipse%5D%20is:question%20created:2013-11-28)

Comment: How I can bookmark this query. Do I need to enter date in query daily or Is there any JavaScript which does this automatically

Comment: @ChandrayyaGK - Not sure about JavaScript. But for a simple use you can just bookmark this query. And change the date whenever you use it. It won't take more time.

Comment: @ChandrayyaGK - Also, if you want to access today's (i.e. latest) questions just remove `created` and search through the [newest tab](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bjava%5d%20or%20%5beclipse%5d%20is%3aq)