# Searching for questions which only contains selected tags and nothing more

Tags: support, tags, search, tag-search

How do I search for questions which only contains selected tags and nothing more?

For example, I need to see the question of which tags are only `[c#]` and `[Winforms]`. If I search for `[c#]` and `[Winforms]` tags it will list all questions which contain `[c#]` and `[Winforms]` tags. so It means the question may be tagged like this: `[C#]`,`[Linq]`,`[SQL]`; But I can not answer this question because it is also related to SQL.

I'm looking for questions those their tags are only and only `[c#]` and `[Winforms]` tags. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just like [Search for singleton tags on questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148977/295232), it's currently only possible with a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1030184/all-questions-with-exactly-two-specified-tags?tag1=c%23&tag2=winforms).

[image]

But since there are many tags which don't have any influence on your ability to answer the question, it's probably better to focus on a few tags which you want to exclude, e.g.

```
[c#] [winforms] -[linq] -[sql]
```

([results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+%5Bc%23%5D+%5Bwinforms%5D+-%5Blinq%5D+-%5Bsql%5D&mixed=1))

---

You can [fork](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/fork/1030184) the query to add additional constraints, like [no answers at all](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1031123/all-unanswered-questions-with-exactly-two-specified-tags?tag1=c%23&tag2=winforms) or [no accepted answer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1031124/all-questions-with-exactly-two-specified-tags-and-no-accepted-answer?tag1=c%23&tag2=winforms). If you're new to SEDE and/or SQL, don't forget to take the awesome [tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) which will help you getting started.

Comment: great query, but how about adding an option which user can only list unanswered questions or questions which have answers but none of them are accepted?

Comment: See the last paragraph of the updated answer :)

Comment: Thanks for your update ;)

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the query from @Glorfindel, this [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1030511?tags=winforms%3Bc%23) let you select all not closed questions that have an arbitrary number of tags. You can enter two, three, four tags separated by semi-colons.

```sql
-- will hold our selected tags
create table #selectedtags(value nvarchar(35) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS)

-- fill selectedtags based on the ; delimited tags 
insert into
#selectedtags
select rtrim(ltrim(value))
from string_split(##tags:string?winforms;linq##, ';')

-- select posts
select p.id as [Post Link]
     , p.creationdate
     , p.score
     , p.tags
from posts p
inner join posttags pt 
        on pt.postid = p.id  -- for each tag per post a row 
inner join tags t 
        on t.id = pt.tagid  -- which tag
inner join #selectedtags st 
        on st.value = t.tagname -- select the tags
-- check if the post doesn't have more tags
where (select count(*) 
       from posttags pc 
       where pc.postid = p.id) = (select count(*) 
                                  from #selectedtags)
and closeddate is not null
-- have the exact count of tags                                 
group by p.id 
     , p.creationdate
     , p.score
     , p.tags
having count(*) = (select count(*) 
                   from #selectedtags)
```

Keep in mind SEDE is only updated once a week, on Sunday.

Comment: great query, but how about adding an option which user can only list unanswered questions or questions which have answers but none of them are accepted?

Comment: That is adding in the where clause: `and (p.answercount = 0 or p.acceptedanswerid is null)` I leave that as an exercise  for the reader.