# Proposal to use review queues for tag cleanup

Tags: feature-request, tags, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Repurpose the new review system for large-scale tagging operations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137706/repurpose-the-new-review-system-for-large-scale-tagging-operations)

The new review queues are awesome. I would like to be able to tag a tag* in such a way that all questions with that tag would come up for a special kind of review.

The scenario would look something like this:

1. A tag is identified as problematic. Maybe it's a meta-tag, maybe the site scope has changed, maybe it's just commonly problematic for one reason or another.
2. A discussion on meta would determine how the tag should be cleaned up.
3. Once there was consensus about how to go about with the cleanup work, a moderator would create a special review-queue and add the tag in question. The header for the queue would have a link to the meta post and any brief instructions for what to look for, common re-tag or edit options, etc.

I think this would help us get more people involved with housekeeping jobs that improve the overall quality of the site.

* <sub>This is meta, right?</sub>

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137706/repurpose-the-new-review-system-for-large-scale-tagging-operations

Comment: @MadScientist: Ya found that too late. I already VTC'ed my own question here ... do you think it's actually a duplicate or a is there something fundamentally different that these should stand as two proposals?